# Use D-operators to find a particular solution that satisfies initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working throuhg finding a particular solution of $$y''-5y'+6y=2e^{3x}cos(x)$$ and then find the general solution.

I have worked out so far
$$y_h= r^2-5r+6=0$$
$$=3,2$$
$$y_h=c_1e^{3x}+c_2e^{2x}$$
The particular solution 
$$y=1/(D^2-5D+6) 2e^{3x}*Re(e^{ix})$$
$$y=Re[2e^{(3+i)x}* 1/(d^2-5D+6)]$$
Sub D for $$(3+i+D)$$
$$y=Re[2e^{(3+i)x}* \frac{1}{(3+i+D)^2-5(3+i+D)+6}]$$
$$y=Re[2e^{(3+i)x}*\frac{1}{(D^2+D-1+i+2Di)}]$$

I can't figure out how to get the remainder of the particular solution. Can any one help me

Comment: Are you trying to use the theorem $\frac{1}{p(D)} \left ( e^{ax} f(x) \right ) = e^{ax} \left ( \frac{1}{p(D+a)} f(x) \right )$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your last line:
$$y=Re[2e^{(3+i)x}*\frac{1}{(D^2+D-1+i+2Di)}1]$$
Because $\frac 1 {f(D)}e^a=\frac 1 {f(a)}$ and you have here $a=0$. Since $1=e^0$.
$$y=Re[2e^{(3+i)x}\frac{1}{(-1+i)}]$$
$$y=2e^{3x}Re[e^{ix}\frac{1}{(-1+i)}]$$
Apply Euler's formula:
$$y=2e^{3x}Re[(\cos x+ i \sin x)\frac{1}{(-1+i)}]$$
Multiply by $i+1$:
$$y=-e^{3x}Re[(\cos x+ i \sin x)(i+1)]$$
Keeping the real part gives us:
$$ \boxed {y_p(x)=e^{3x}(\sin x -\cos x )}$$

---

**Another way:**
$$y''-5y'+6y=2e^{3x}\cos(x)$$
For the particular solution:
$$
\begin{align}
y_p&=\frac 2 {D^2-5D+6}e^{3x}\cos(x) \\
y_p&=e^{3x}\frac 2 {D^2+D}\cos(x) \\
y_p&=e^{3x}\frac 2 {D-1}\cos(x) \\
y_p&=2e^{3x}\frac {D+1} {D^2-1}\cos(x) \\
y_p&=-e^{3x} {(D+1)} \cos(x) \\
y_p&=-e^{3x}(\cos x -\sin x ) \\
\end{align}
$$
Finally:
$$y_p=e^{3x}(\sin x -\cos x )$$

Comment: Thankyou so much. This has helped me a lot!!!

Comment: You're welcomed ...@KatL

Comment: @KatL Fon't forget that an operator D is acting on something thats why you have $1$ . And $e^0=1$ so I applied the formula for this case. After that it's just algebra with complex numbers.